# how to use both solid brush and imagebrush in listview.background

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, brush

The problem i have is how to use both the solid brush and imagebrush tags in listview.bakcground? I have set an image as background in listview but i m not able to set any color to the background?

```
 <ListView.Background>
   <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images\ViewIcons\cls.png" Opacity="0.05" />
 </ListView.Background>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will set the same property i.e `Background` then later will overwrite the value of former so do it like this

```
<Border Background="Red">
        <ListView >

        <ListView.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images\Q3.png" Opacity=".05" />
        </ListView.Background>
        </ListView>
        </Border>
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: oh this was helpful. But the thing is i m using the listview inside the grid so the background is filled even beyond the listview